# Converting from letter into a word

Tags: c++, string, debugging, assertion

Overall this is a small portion of the assignment but this function is giving me an error "Debug Assertion Failed!"

```
void English_to_SMS(void)
{
    int i;
    bool vowel;
    string word;
    string letter;

    cout << "Enter y, n or m: ";
    cin >> word;
    for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); ++i)
    {
        letter = word[i];
        if (letter == "y") {
        cout << "yes";
        }
        else if (letter == "n") {
            cout << "no";
        }
        else if (letter == "m") {
            cout << "maybe";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << letter ;
    }
}
```

I took a screenshot of the error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGq98.png

The error says:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program:
>   ..ects]English.SMS_Translator\Debug\English._SMS_Translator.exe
>   File:e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring Line:1440
>
> Expression: string subscript out of range
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press retry to debug the application)

Any help or suggestion to solve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); ++i)
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
```

Subscript ranges of N-sized container go from 0 to N-1

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling for a long time for this.

Comment: Yes all indexing in C++ is 0 based, so think of all indexing as 0 to n-1 and you shouldn't go far wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your function. The main mistake is that it is unclear what the function does.:) Either it asks the user to enter only a single character or a word of characters.

The valid range of indices for class std::string is [0, length() -1]. So instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); ++i)
```

there must be

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
```

But it would be even better if you would write

```
for ( string::size_type i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i )
```

The secons mistake is the declaration of variable i

```
void English_to_SMS(void)
{
    int i;
```

that is not used in the function because in the for loop you declare another local variable i that hides the previous declaration. So you may remove statement

```
    int i;
```

Also I do not see any sense to declare an object of type std::string that to keep only one character. So instead of declaration

```
string letter;
```

I would use declaration

```
char letter;
```

For example

```
char letter;
//...

    letter = word[i];
    if (letter == 'y') {
```

Declaration

```
bool vowel;
```

is also not used in the function.